# The convergence of $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose $\lim_{n \to \infty } b_n / a_n = 1$ , $b_n$ is bounded and $a_n$ is an increasing sequence   (For all $n$ we have $a_n , b_n \gt 0$) . What we can say about the convergence of $a_n$ and $b_n $ ? I think $a_n$ has to be convergent and $b_n$ can be convergent or divergent .

Comment: If $b_n$ is bounded, then it can't be divergent, no? It is just bounded... can this help? What about $\lim_{n \to \infty } M / a_n$, where $M \geq b_n$?

Comment: For example $b_n = (-1)^n$ is divergent .

Comment: No, $(-1)^n$ is not divergent!!! It has no limit, but this does not mean that it is divergent... be careful!

Comment: $b_n = n$ is divergent, $b_n = n^2$ is divergent... they go to $\infty$. But $(-1)^n$ does not!!!

Comment: @the_candyman Why $(-1)^n$ isn't divergent ? You can easily prove that using contradiction .

Comment: @the_candyman Yes, $x_n=(-1)^n$ defines a sequence $(x_n)$ which is **divergent**. Please check your definitions.

Comment: @Did maybe I'm wrong... I always considered as divergent any series such that $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} b_n = \pm \infty$$...

Comment: @the_candyman We have different kinds of divergence . Diverging to $\infty$ is one of them .

Comment: I'm used to say that $b_n = (-1)^n$ does not converge, nor diverge. My fault, sorry.

Comment: @the_candyman No problem , thanks for answering . I think the definition of convergence is very important here .

Comment: See the answer below it shows that both sequences converge to the same limite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{  b_n }{a_n} = 1$$

implies there exists N such that for $n>N$ we have

$$ \left|\left|\frac{  b_n }{a_n}\right|-1\right|\le
\left|\frac{  b_n }{a_n}-1\right|<\frac12$$ which leads to

$$\frac12\le  \left|\frac{  b_n }{a_n}\right| \le \frac32~~~~for~~~n>N$$
which implies

$$ | a_n| \le 2  |b_n|\le M~~~~for~~~n>N$$

thus since $b_n$ is bounded,  the sequence  $a_n$ is also bounded and increasing . this means that $a_n$ converge to some limit $\ell$

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty } b_n =   \lim_{n \to \infty }   a_n      \cdot  \lim_{n \to \infty } b_n/a_n =\ell.$$

Comment: Why $\lim_{n \to \infty } b_n / a_n = 1$ implies $\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{  a_n }{b_n} = 1 $ ?

Comment: if a sequence a sequence converged it's inverse converges too. is that not true?

Comment: For example consider $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1/n = 0$ but $n$ is divergent .

Comment: in fact you can forget about that it does not matter . use the inequality below you will still get the result .

Comment: See the edit now I don't want get into that . by limit I implicily meant the limit is different from 0

Comment: Thanks . Great answer !

Answer (score 1):

Since $a_n$ is increasing, it either converges to some value or diverges to $+\infty.$ If it converges to some value $a_n\to a$, then since $\frac{b_n}{a_n} \to  1,$ we have $b_n\to a.$ If $a_n\to \infty,$ then since $b_n$ is bounded, $\frac{b_n}{a_n}\to 0$ so this case is impossible. So we have $a_n \to a$ and $b_n\to a$ for some real $a>0.$

Comment: Thank you for the answer .